# Generating edge table from nodes using QGIS

Tags: postgresql, network-analysis

I generated nodes from a line road network in QGIS and uploaded them to PostgreSQL/PostGIS. I would really like to use them for network analysis and I am wondering if anyone knows  if, from these nodes, I can generate an edge table based on adjacent nodes. Doesn't need to have reverse cost or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Just a short description, but perhaps it helps to create a workflow. I have worked on such network modelling exercise in ArcGIS Pro, but I am sure there is a similar workflow in PostgreSQL/PostGIS.  Process is the following:

1. First, from your nodes table, calculate the N number of adjacent nodes in QGIS using the *Distance Matrix tool*. By specifying your nodes table as the input layer and near layer (using FID as unique id), you can calculate a distance matrix that either connects all nodes to all others, or set a limited number of nodes based on distance.
2. After calculating the distance matrix, use two separate join queries to add the XY information from the nodes table to and join it with the input and near/target id in the distance matrix table (based on the unique column id).
3. Use this new distance matrix table with XY information to calculate lines/edges between the corresponding input and target XY coordinate columns. You can either do this in PostGIS using the ST_MakeLine command,  or in QGIS using the Shape Tools plugin and the XY to line function.
4. The resulting table will provide a basic edge table based on just the nodes.